# Unique ID for Android device

Tags: android, sha, imei

I need an ID which will be unique for each device.  This ID will be stored in the server and will be used to identify a device. I am thinking of using IMEI number but I dont want to send the IMEI number to server for privacy reason.

So, I am thinking of doing this

> 1. Get IMEI number.
> 2. Hash the IMEI number using SHA-1.
> 3. Send this to server

Is this a reliable way of getting unique device ID without privacy concerns? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Get IMEI number using following

```
 String identifier = null;
 TelephonyManager tm =   (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 if (tm != null)
  identifier = tm.getDeviceId();
 if (identifier == null || identifier .length() == 0)
  identifier = Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

and add this permission :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANDROID_ID but in certain devices it is a bug and it seems to return the same id. Check the reference for the same https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/U4mOUI-rRPY. As a fall back i do the following:

```
 String deviceId = Secure.getString(ActivationActivity.this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                                      if ("9774d56d682e549c".equals(deviceId)) {
                                        deviceId=  UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
                                      }
```